# Ransack: Search has_many through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am a newbie in Rails and have issues with Ransack:

This is model Project

```
 class Project < ApplicationRecord
  searchkick
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :m_category
  has_many :project_industries, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :m_industries, through: :project_industries

end
```

This is model Industry:

```
 class Industry < ApplicationRecord
  include M
  belongs_to :m_industry_category
  has_many :project_industries, dependent: :destroy, foreign_key: :industry_id
  has_many :projects, through: :project_industries
end
```

And this is model IndustryCategory:

```
 class IndustryCategory < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :industries, dependent: :destroy,
    foreign_key: :industry_category_id

  has_many :projects, through: :industries
end
```

Now, I want to search the Project by `IndustryCategory` but I don't know how. please help me!! tks

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this

```
@industrty_category = IndustryCategory.find(params[:id])

@project = @industry_category.projects.all
```

Comment: i think it not search by Ransack :(

Comment: I did not get what you are trying to say can you please explain properly.

Comment: I have given you AR query so you can use Ransack accordingly.